# Getting the background image on my homepage centered like my other pages

Tags: css, wordpress, background, background-image

I am almost done with [my WordPress website](http://blackbottle.com.au/) that's using the Pique theme.  The one problem is that on mobile, the background image on the homepage is left-justified and doesn't change sizes with the screen size. On the Menu and Drinks pages, the background looks perfect on mobile.

So the goal is to get the header background image on the homepage to look like it does on the Menu and Drinks pages.

I've tried playing around a lot with the code I already have to edit the automatic overlay the theme comes with:

```
.pique-panel-background::before {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0);
}

.pique-panel-background {
    opacity: 1 !important;
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 1024px;
    /* Set up proportionate scaling */
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    /* Set up positioning */
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

I've also tried using the classes .body.custom-background, changing min-height and min-width, changing the position of the background to fixed or center or top center, maybe I'm just using the wrong callout but I can't find the name of the element! tried an @media callout I found on a few forums but can't get it to work right.

I bet my problem is that I am not using the right element callout because everything I've tried mostly hasn't changed anything :/

Comment: try removing `min-width: 1024px` from `.pique-panel-background`

Comment: I messed around with your CSS and think I have the fix for you.  The reason why the pages images are giving you an issue is the homepage is a background image and the menu/drinks are just images not background images.


`.pique-panel-background {background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;} `


Remove the `min-width` as suggested by Michael Coker

Comment: Sorry forgot to add this to my comment:  Right now the CSS property is getting overwritten by a CSS style in the `@media (min-width:768px)` . I would change it there if you can.

Comment: Thank you so much @MichaelCoker I finally got it to work!!!! <3

Comment: And @dreamweaver (sorry couldn't tag you both at once). The 50% 50% I think made it work